# JQuery set text to an input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set some text to in input text field, but is does not work. What am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="link_input_text" value="" name="" type="text" />
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('link_input_text').val("Some text");
    </script>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$('.link_input_text').val("Some text");` You need to use class selector

Comment: missing `.` - `$('.link_input_text').val("Some text");` - you need to use a class selector

Comment: Have you iimported jquery? It's not in your code, which appears to be the complete document.  If you have, the `.` comments above are relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$('link_input_text').val("Some text");
```

to this:

```
$('.link_input_text').val("Some text");
```

You have to use CSS-like selectors to select elements in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery **[Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**

Use this

```
$('.link_input_text').val("Some text");
```

Instead of

```
$('link_input_text').val("Some text");
```

```js
$(".link_input_text").val("Some Text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="link_input_text" value="" name="" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<input class="link_input_text" value="" name="" type="text" />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.link_input_text').val("Some text");
</script>
</html>
```